# How to determine the reason of a CrashLoopBackOff error in a Spring Boot application deployed on Kubernetes

Tags: docker, spring-boot, kubernetes

I have a Spring Boot application, deployed on a docker container on Kubernetes. The application works well for some time (hours) but at a certain moment it starts restarting like crazy showing a CrashLoopBackOff error state.

This is the info I get from the dead pod:

```
Port:       8080/TCP
State:      Waiting
  Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
Last State:     Terminated
  Reason:       Error
  Exit Code:    137
  Started:      Fri, 11 Aug 2017 10:15:03 +0200
  Finished:     Fri, 11 Aug 2017 10:16:22 +0200
Ready:      False
Restart Count:  7
...
    Volume Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-bhk8f (ro)
    Environment Variables:
      JAVA_OPTS:        -Xms512m -Xmx1792m
Conditions:
  Type      Status
  Initialized   True 
  Ready     False 
  PodScheduled  True 
...
QoS Class:  BestEffort
Tolerations:    <none>
No events.
```

**Is there any way to get more detailed information about the cause of the crashes?**

**Is 137 error code an out of memory error?** I have kept increasing the memory of the Java process from -Xmx768m up to 1792m, but errors keep showing up. **Could it be something else?**

**One weird fact:** I need to find out how come the application runs well, after some hours the pod is killed and then every restart is killed after only some seconds executing.

Comment: So on your nodes do a `docker ps -a` to see exited containers and see what you get in logs. Also Just giving memory limit inside container wont help, you would need to also apply that to the container. Also check if there is a disk space issue. We had a similar issue where tomcat would core dump and the dump was huge causing the 10GB container to have no space inside

Comment: Without telemetry it's almost impossible to say. Might be a leak and you get OOMed, who knows :)

What are you using to monitor the system and your containers?

Comment: Just to be clear: yes, code 137 comes from the Docker engine indicating OOM kill, but we need a root cause, right?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I'll try to `docker ps -a` in the kubernetes node. I don't understand this: `Also Just giving memory limit inside container wont help, you would need to also apply that to the container`. Our dockerfile runs the java process setting -Xms and -Xmx limits, I thought that applied to the cointainer. If not, how can I do it?

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas We are monitoring with Prometheus + Grafana and can see the memory evolution per pod. As you say it could be anything, so how to determine the root cause?

Comment: Do the container logs show anything?

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski how can I see the container logs? The app logs don't show anything wrong

Comment: To set the limits maybe check out my post here: https://hackernoon.com/container-resource-consumption-too-important-to-ignore-7484609a3bb7

Comment: did you look at the node system log file, sometime it will have some useful information. also see you can increase the health check interval little more.

Answer (score 1):

`kubectl logs podName containerName` will provide you with the container logs which should give you additional information about the cause of the error.

Comment: kubectl logs shows application logs and there everything seems ok. Is there a way to get more specific info about a crashed container?

Comment: I wouldn't think so. Besides using other potential metrics. Is the exit code provided in the logs? What is the exit code (when the process terminates)?